# How to search and store the line number of which in the data was found? (Python)

Tags: python

I am currently developing a program for my local charity and would like to ask how to get the program to 
1) Search a notepad file for a specific Word(s)
2) Store which line that the name was found on

My code so far :

```
import time

def AddToDatabase():
    print ("\nYou are adding to the Database. \nA)Continue \nB)Go Back")
    ATD = input(": ")
    if ATD == "A" or ATD == "a":

    Name = input("\nEnter Name of Member [First Name and Surname]: ")
    with open("Name.txt", "a") as N:
        N.write("\n{}".format(Name))
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\nAdding...")
    time.sleep(1)

    print ("\nEnter Address of "+Name+" all on one line")
    print ("In format [Include Commas]")
    print ("\nRoad name with house number [e.g. 1 Morgan Way], Borough [e.g Harrow], City [e.g London], Postcode [e.g. HA5 2EF]")
    Address = input("\n: ")
    with open("Address.txt", "a") as A:
        A.write("\n{}".format(Address))
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\nAdding...")
    time.sleep(1)

    Home_Number = input("\nEnter Home Number of "+Name+": ")
    with open("Home Number.txt", "a") as HN:
        HN.write("\n{}".format(Home_Number))
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\nAdding...")
    time.sleep(1)

    Mobile_Number = input ("\nEnter Mobile Number of "+Name+": ")
    with open("Mobile Number.txt", "a") as MN:
        MN.write("\n{}".format(Mobile_Number))
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\nAdding...")
    time.sleep(1)

    Email_Address = input ("\nEnter Email Address of "+Name+": ")
    with open("Email Address.txt", "a") as EA:
        EA.write("\n{}".format(Email_Address))
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\nAdding...")
    time.sleep(1)

    Dietry_Needs = input("\nEnter Medical/Dietry Needs of "+Name+": ")
    with open("Medical Dietry Needs.txt", "a") as MDN:
        MDN.write("\n{}".format(Dietry_Needs))
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("\nAdding...")
    time.sleep(1)

    print ("All information for "+Name+" has been added. Redirecting Back To Main...")
    time.sleep(5)
    Main()

elif ATD == "B" or ATD == "b":
    Main()

def CheckDatabase():
    print ("\nSPACE SAVED")

def Main():
    print ("\nSVA of UK Database")
    while True:
    print ("\nA)Check Database \nB)Add to Database \nC)Exit Program")
    choice = input(": ")

    if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
        CheckDatabase()

    elif choice == "B" or choice == "b":
        AddToDatabase()

    elif choice == "C" or choice == "c":
        break

    else:
        print ("Invalid Input")
        Main()

Main()
```

How would try to search for example 'John Smith' in a txt file and store which line that name was found on? I know i may have maybe come across confusing but if you don't get it then please leave a comment and ill answer what you dont get! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to emulate `grep`?

Comment: What is that? @devnull

Comment: It looks like you are trying to write a "database". There are plenty of good free databases available, from Sqlite to Postgresql; why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thank You i will check them out now

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic...

```
found_line = None
with open(filename) as f:

    pattern = "john smith"
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if pattern in line:
            found_line = i
            print "Found %s in %i" % (pattern, i)
```

Comment: How would i store the line its found on to a variable? (Btw this works thank you very much!)